# Fatal Error: Call to undefined function drupal_mail()

Tags: 6

Very new to drupal, I am playing around with the mail function to test how I can send mails using drupals API.

I used this tutorial from [treversimonton.com](http://www.trevorsimonton.com/blog/drupalmail-example-tutorial-explanation).

Whenever I try to call the PHPScript which should send the test mail, i get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_mail() in
>   /drupal_dev/sites/all/modules/configurator/Trader/PHPScripts/testMail.php
>   on line 14

Fyi: my configurator.module is located in /drupal_dev/sites/all/modules/configurator/. I saw a couple of examples where the drupal_mail() function is implemented in the .module file, but the tutorial mentioned above said I may place this function anywhere.

So what am I doing wrong?

Here goes my code:

```
$to = "recipient@host.com";
$email_from = "donotreply@host.com";

$params['var'] = 'test_var1';
$params['more'] = 'test_var2';

$sent = drupal_mail('testMail', 'key', $to, language_default(), $params, $email_from, TRUE );

if (!$sent)
{
    echo "Failure";
} else
{
    echo "Success";
}

//drupal mail looks for a function that matches the first parameter _ mail to build the message
function testMail_mail($key, &$message, $params)
{
    $language = $message['language'];
    switch ($key) 
    {
        case 'key': 
            $message['subject'] = t('Subject', $vars, $language->language);
            $message['body'][] = "Hallo Jannik. This is the body of the email, and might contain vars from params.";
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Create custom module instead of php file.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan If I am trying to use my custom module in this php file ( `include_once '../../configurator.module` ) I am getting the error `Fatal error: call to undefined function drupal_get_path()`

Comment: @Mołot could you please give me a hint how the question mentioned by you could help me solve my problem? I don't see any parallels :(

Comment: When you are using external script and want to have access to Drupal's functions, you need to bootstrap Drupal. It appears this is exactly what you want and you only didn't know the name of that process.

Comment: @Mołot Thank you for your help :) It now works. I used the answer to this question to bootstrap drupal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014244/drupal-how-to-access-to-drupals-apis-with-a-standalone-php-script 

If you want feel free to post this as answer and i will accept it to give you the rep for your help :)